# Includegraphics and double-dot

Tags: includegraphics

Good morning everyone,

I'm having a hard time trying to include figures with a double-point (:) in their name in a LaTeX figure.
I'm already using some brackets in order to include single points (.) in the names of my figures.
Does anyone know how I could make it work?

Example:

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]

\centering

\includegraphics[width=8cm]{{dir/name_part1.name_part2:name_part3}.png}

\end{figure}
```

Comment: colons work by default, you have provided no usable example but I would guess that you are using a babel language that makes : a shortcut character with an active definition, you can turn shorthands off, or use `\string:`

Comment: Multiple dots should work out of the box with the new graphics core. If you have an ancient LaTeX system, then package `grffile` can be used to add support for multiple dots.

Comment: The curly braces are part of the file name: directory is `{dir` and the file name if `name_part1.name_part2:name_part3}.png`. Try without the curly braces.